# OpenCart 3 Storage Folder Conundrum

Tags: php, file, opencart, opencart-3

So I understand that moving the storage outside of the document root will ensure max security and blah blah, but what I can't understand is why I can't move the storage folder into a another folder so I can properly organize it. What I was trying to do was this C:/wamp/storage-multiple/storage1. Why can't I do that? Why is it giving me an invalid path error? I tried it manually and I'm getting nasty PHP errors saying it failed to open. Maybe I'm a file system noob but I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out the answer. Delete DIR_SYSTEM and just have the path alone there. Afterwards just move the storage folder and it'll work.